# Can the verb "increment" refer to a quantity other than one?

Tags: verbs, redundancy

For instance:

> Every time the user logs in, increment the `login` variable.

vs

> Every time the user logs in, increment the `login` variable by 1.

Which is more correct? My gut tells me the first example is correct, and in the case of a number other than one, one should use "increase" instead of "increment".

Comment: In mathematics and computer programming, yes.

Comment: Hi henrebotha: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange! Have you consulted a dictionary? If your question can simply be answered by consulting a basic reference resource, it should not be posted here. If you have trouble researching the question, or still have questions after you do so, please edit your question or create a new one if this one is later closed. (I recommemd closing as off-topic, general reference.)

Comment: Every year they give me an increment in my salary.  I *hope* it is more than one dollar!

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, the full (subscription-only) OED doesn't even list ***increment*** as a verb at all.

Comment: @GEdgar - Had better watch out -- it might just be a penny!

Comment: @FumbleFingers My impression is that the verb use is mostly popular in technical fields. Maybe this use is not considered significant enough? (This re-verbing is also somewhat strange but I imagine that is less of a factor for inclusion.)

Comment: @Håkan: I've used *increment* as a verb in software contexts (almost always implying *increment by **one***) for over thirty years. But I'd probably avoid that usage unless speaking to someone with a programming background. Really, I think it's on a par with other "technical verbs" like *left-shift, push, pop*. So maybe my "somewhat surprisingly" above just reflects the fact that I happen to have a programming background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [verb
>   {WITH OBJECT} chiefly *Computing*
>  
>   Cause a discrete increase in {a numerical quantity}](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/increment)

--Oxford Dictionaries

> [verb COMPUTING
>
>   1.
>   cause a discrete increase in {a numerical quantity}.](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+increment&oq=define+increment)

--Google Search define operator

> [Verb increment {third-person singular simple present increments, present participle incrementing, simple past and past participle incremented}
>
>
>   intransitive, transitive
>  To increase by steps or by a step, especially by one.
>
>
>   1890, H. E. J. G. Du Bois, “On Magnetic Circuits”, Philosophical magazine‎, page 346:  
>
>  ... any given value just before observing, the actual pressures must as frequently be incremented as decremented, both in the "on" and the "off" series.
>
>
>   2007 Jan 23, “Busiest two weeks for recruiters”, Recruiter Magazine:
>
>
>   public sector professional services recruitment, has seen a strong seasonal upturn which has incremented year on year since 2002 by an average of 12%.
>
>
>   1984, Brian W. Kernighan; Rob Pike, The UNIX programming environment, page 124:
>
>
>   The first for loop looks at each word in the input line, incrementing the element of array num subscripted by the word.
>
>
>   Usage notes
>
>   Used in many technical fields, especially in mathematics and computing.](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/increment)

--Wiktionary

Answer (score 1):

In non-computerese it doesn't need to refer to a single unit, though often it does.

Etymonline says it comes from

> mid-15c., "act or process of increasing," from Latin *incrementum* "growth, increase; an addition," from stem of *increscere* "to grow in or upon" (see *increase*).

We often refer to something increasing by a small amount as "increasing only incrementally" to stem the notion that the increase was great or significant. But the increase doesn't have to be a single unit, and most often it is not. Sometimes a single unit doesn't even make much sense, as when a probability increases, or something increases by a percentage.

In programming, however, when you increment a variable it implies 1 unless there is a specific other amount. (Cf. the "increment" operator in C-syntax languages. The `++` always means `+=1` and the decrement operator (`--`) always means `-=1`.) When might there be such another amount? When you need to quantize values so that, say, a 3 or a 6 must round up or down to produce always a "five" block. This is by far the exception, however. Absent any other information, you should assume you must increment by 1. Note also that when there *is* a specific other value to be incremented, that amount will, or should be, explicit: e.g., "increment by 5."

Comment: To this, I will add that even when *increment* does specifically imply 1, saying *increment by one* is still exactly as correct as saying *increment*. It is merely redundant. Redundancy is not incorrect. It is merely redundant. I have just shortened the question title by 50% percent without changing the meaning. That does not mean that the original title was "less correct". It is not a rule of English, or any language, that every word that can be left out, must be left out.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: In my opinion, there's certainly a difference between acceptable redundancy and unacceptable redundancy. For instance, "continue on" is unacceptable to me. So while I agree that "increment by one" is redundant, the question is whether or not that redundancy is acceptable.

Comment: @henrebotha: "increment by one" is certainly an acceptable redundancy. It might seem over-careful, but sometimes it pays to be sure you are understood precisely.

Comment: @henrebotha "unacceptable to me" does not mean "incorrect", though. These are two entirely different things. Just because you happen to not like apples, does not mean apples are wrong. The question you asked originally was not "which alternative do I, henrebotha, like more", but "which alternative is more correct". To the former, we'd have no answer anyway. We can't know what you personally deem acceptable and why. "Continue on" is impeccable English, and COCA has 1061 cites for it (vs. only 253 for "cold beer" and 11 for "orange car"). And if you think about it, "go on" is no less redundant.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: One can "go back", or "go elsewhere", but to "continue" is to keep going in the direction one was going.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming contexts, "increment", unqualified, means "increment by one".  A larger increment is still an increment, so "increment by five" is equally correct.

in Visual BASIC, for example:

FOR X= 1 TO 10

the increment is implied, and it is one.

FOR X = 1 TO 10 STEP 1

ok to explicitly describe the increment value, too

FOR x = 1 TO 10 STEP 2

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm talking about using natural language in a programming context, not using a programming language.

Comment: ... and a smaller step is also still an increment ... `FOR X FROM 0.0 TO 1.0 BY 0.01`